# Working with lists

Tags: string, haskell

I am a beginner, and write implementation of hangman in haskell. 
Necessary to show guessed characters in '***'-like string, currently I use that code:

```
proceed char word progress = let zprog = zip progress [0..] in
    foldl (\a x -> a ++ [fst x]) "" $ map (f char word) zprog where    
        f c w el = 
            if c == w !! (snd el) then
                (c, snd el)
            else
                el
```

If word was "shadow" and progress like "******", char = 's' function return "s****".

How can I rewrite that function? I see that its not clean solution.
Solution (by @luqui):

```
proceed char = zipWith combine where
    combine x y
        | x == char = char
        | otherwise = y
```

("word" and "progress" arguments transfers to zipWith becose haskell's eta-reduction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to think of `zip`, you just seem to have done some extra work.  See if you can write a suitable helper function `combine`:

```
proceed char word progress = zipWith combine word progress
    where
    combine :: Char -> Char -> Char
    combine = ?
```

Comment: For extra fun, try deleting all occurrences of `word` and `progress` from the source of this function

Comment: Wow, reduction (dont sure about the name), I read about it, thanks.

Comment: specifically "eta reduction"

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot the name of 'η'. Thanks very much!